# Get rid of all @Override errors in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding

Is there a way to just comment out all the @Overrides that turn out to be Eclipse errors that prevent your app from building/running?

Comment: (Other than manually finding all 234234 instances..)

Comment: Why do you want to remove so many overrides? Usually, Override tells you that there's something wrong with your methods signature... removing the Overrides therefore usually removes the warning, not the problem.

Comment: are they errors (red), or warnings (yellow)? 
if theyre the red ones, then getting rid of them wont help your application build, the methods that you are overriding will need to be fixed

Comment: They are all warnings. In general, commenting them out makes it run. o.O

Answer (score 10):

So if i understand you there are already @Override annotations in your source code, but you are getting compile errors on them?

If so you have the wrong jdk installed.

You need at least jdk1.5 to use those annotations on methods derived from classes.

You need at least jdk1.6 to use those annotations on methods derived from interfaces.

Comment: +1 for that. Using Java 5 instead of 6 and getting a bunch of errors because of @Override on implemented interface methods is the most often case.

Comment: I am using 1.6 according to java -version - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-10M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode)

Answer (score 9):

In

> Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings

There is a group called "`Annotations`". Under there, check that the

"Missing '@Override' annotation is set to "Ignore" or "Warning" and not "Error".

Edit: I wanted to add that you can get Eclipse to automatically add @Override annotations on files that you save in the Save Actions.

> Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions

There is a checkbox for "`Additional Actions`" and if you open the "`Configure`" window you can select the "`Missing Code`" tab and select "`Add Missing Annotations`" where you can select which annotations to automatically add.

Comment: This seems to be for missing Overrides, but not just ignoring the Overrides that are there anyway

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're compiling against Java 1.5 or earlier, where the compiler treats @Override annotations of interface methods as errors.

Use Eclipse to search and replace (remove) all instances of "@Override". Then add back the non-interface overrides using "Clean Up".

Steps:

1. Select the projects or folders containing your source files.
2. Go to "Search > Search..." (Ctrl-H) to bring up the Search dialog.
3. Go to the "File Search" tab.
4. Enter "@Override" in "Containing text" and "*.java" in "File name patterns". Click "Replace...", then "OK", to remove all instances of "@Override".
5. Go to "Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Clean Up" and create a new profile.
6. Edit the profile, and uncheck everything except "Missing Code > Add missing Annotations > @Override". Make sure "Implementations of interface methods" is unchecked.
7. Select the projects or folders containing your source files.
8. Select "Source > Clean Up..." (Alt+Shift+s, then u), then "Finish" to add back the non-interface overrides.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have Java 8 on my system and facing the same issue in eclipse.
Problem is because JDK Compliance is 1.5

Here is how I fixed it

Open Eclipse,
Preference -> Java -> Compiler -> JDK Compliance

Change it to 1.6

Comment: For some weird reason this is not working for me... it's already set to Java 8 but it still doesn't let me use @Override, acting like it's 1.5.

Comment: Turns out I had to set this property at the project level, not just the global eclipse preferences level.